# Disable Jquery tabs for specific date/day

Tags: jquery, date, tabs

I have JQuery tabs with Day 1, Day 2, Day 3 content. I would like to enable Day 2, Day 3, etc, tabs on their specific date because the event hasn't happened yet hence I don't want users to click the tabs.

Here's the function I use right now to disable the tabs.

```
$('#tabs').tabs({disabled:[2,3,4]});
```

Can I bind the above function with dates? Something like if the date is July 25, to enable the Day 2 tab automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: how do day 2 is associated to July 25???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();
if (d.getMonth() == 6 && d.getDate() == 25)
  // do something
```

Comment: You are wonderful. Thanks. I will iterate it using case switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check for the dates and fill in the `disabled` array properly? I'm afraid you'll have to do it manually, I doubt there is a simple trick to do it.